# Async pipe not working with piped observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following Angular component and HTML and I am wondering why nothing gets displayed. The class gets added (first line of HTML), but I don't see any results even though the service returns data.

```js
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  result$: Observable<SearchResult>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private service: SearchService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.result$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term: string) => this.service.searchTerm(term)),
    );
  }

  search(term: string): void {
    if (term.length >= 2) {
      this.searchTerms.next(term);
    }
  }

  hasResult$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.result$.pipe(
      map(res => (res?.x ?? [] ).length > 0 || (res?.y ?? []).length > 0),
    );
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'with-results': (result$ | async)}">
  <div class="input-box">
    <input #searchBox type="text" (input)="search(searchBox.value)">
  </div>
  <ul class="search-results" *ngIf="hasResult$() | async">
    <li *ngFor="let result of (result$ | async)?.x">
        {{ result.name }}
    </li>        
    <li *ngFor="let result of (result$ | async)?.y">
        {{ result.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Probably a simple mistake but I can't get my head wrapped around it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have 2 different issues here.

*1. x either y*

If either `y` or `x` exists in `result`, then `hasResult` will be true and the `ngIf` will render the content. If now only `y` exists, `x` will be `undefined` and create an error since `undefined` is not iterable.

*2. Late subscribers*

Your `ngIf` renders the list after the search. However, you subscribe to `result$` in those `ngFor` loops after that. You will need to make sure that those late subscriber receive the value.

The fastest way, even tho not the cleanest way, would be to just add a `shareReplay` operator.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.result$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term: string) => this.service.searchTerm(term)),
      shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I suggest `shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }),` - that is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code and the calls. If you define an interface

```
export interface resultType {
  x?: { name?: string }[];
  y?: { name?: string }[];
}
```

You can use in .html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{result:result$|async} as data">
    <ul class="search-results" *ngIf="data.result?.x ||data.result?.y" >
        <li *ngFor="let result of data.result?.x">
            {{ result.name }}
        </li>        
        <li *ngFor="let result of data.result?.y">
            {{ result.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a property instead of a method:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.result$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term: string) => this.service.searchTerm(term)),
    );

    this.hasResult$ = this.result$.pipe(
      map(res => (res?.x ?? [] ).length > 0 || (res?.y ?? []).length > 0),
    );
  }
```